# Video Outplay in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Hello I am new in all this, but I have a video set on my banner of the website I building, but now with the new policy of Chrome my video just stop, is any way I can code for changes this new behavior, and force the autoplay of the banner video thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn’t be much of a policy if you could force it. You must always assume that autoplay might not happen and provide a play button.

Comment: Is no like that is just we need to add muted to the video and them is work normal.